# How to calculate the volume between the 2 surfaces $x^2+y^2=z $ & $2x+2y+z=2$

Tags: integration

I know that I will use double integration or triple and how to bring the limits of integration  ,but my problem is that I do not know which surface I will subtract from who should I say$ (2-2x-2y)- x^2-y^2$ , or $(x^2+y^2)-(2-2x-2y)$???

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a Mathematica plot of the two surfaces. Does that allow you to answer your question yourself? Anyway, you should, gradually, build up the intuition that the positive definite quadratic will grow faster than anything linear when we move further out from the origin. Then you need to calculate some sample points to get an idea of what happens near the origin.

Comment: The figure difintely  answer my question, but the problem is  what if I can't sketch with that accuracy? Is there any mathematical  way to confirm it ?

Comment: You know where they intersect, right? At least that's how I interpreted you saying that you can find the limits of integration. Then you only need to check at points inside the region you are gonna integrate over.

Answer (score 0):

From the equations of the surfaces $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=2-2x-2y$ their intersection projected to the $xy$ plain given by the following equation $x^2+y^2+2x+2y=2$ or
$$(x+2)^2+(y+2)^2=10.$$
$A:=\{(x,y):(x+2)^2+(y+2)^2\le 10\}$ is a disk of radius $\sqrt{10}$ centered at $(-2,-2)$. (The intersection of the two surfaces can be seen well in the figure attached to the OP.)

So, we have to integrate $1$ over $A$ from $2-2x-2y$ to $x^2+y^2$  with respect to $z$ first:

$$V=\iint_A\left[\int_{2-2x-2y}^{x^2+y^2}\ 1 \ dz\right]\ dxdy.$$

From the description of the circle shaped $A$ we have the equation

$$y^2+2y+x^2+2x-2=0$$

for the boundaries for $y$ given $x$. We get

$$y_{1,2}=-1\pm\sqrt{3-x^2+2x},\,\,\, -2-\sqrt{10}\le x\le -2+\sqrt{10},$$

that is

$$V=\int_{-2-\sqrt{10}}^{-2+\sqrt{10}}\left[\int_{-1-\sqrt{3-x^2+2x}}^{-1+\sqrt{3-x^2+2x}}\left[\int_{2-2x-2y}^{x^2+y^2}\ 1 \ dz\right] \ dy\right]\ dx.$$